# WCSession to check if companion app can receive message

Tags: ios, watchconnectivity, wcsession

Im using `WCSession` to communicate between apple `Watch` and `iOS App`.
on both sides im initiating the `session` with:

```
init() {
   self.session = WCSession.default
   self.session.delegate = self
   self.session.activate()
}
```

also implemented the method to activate the session when he deactivated, when session deactivated i call `session.activate()`

in a case where the companion app is terminated, i want the watch app to get immediate response, instead i get timeout after a minute or so.

tried to use the `WCSession.isreachable` but it always returns true.
is there a way for one of the session sides to check if the other side can receive the message?

thanks!